# Show date in html table using Laravel MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I'm using Carbon API to format date, here is a code I write in view:

`<td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse('@'.$item->time)->format('d-m-Y H-i-s-e') }}</td>`

Date I get in view didn't match with data stored in MongoDB, In MongoDB date is `ISODate("2018-03-31T01:08:50.000+0000")` but I get `"16-10-50214 19-13-20-+00:00"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found a best solution to view date in blade if you are using mongodb:

```
{{ $item['time']->toDateTime()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s e') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `Carbon\Carbon::parse('@'.$item->time)->toIso8601String()`

Comment: thanks for your answer but this time output is '50214-10-16T19:13:20+00:00'