# How to parse date in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date

Below is the code inserted:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse('@'.$item->time)->format('d-m-Y H-i-s-e') }}
```

It is not parsing and giving some error.

Comment: `{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->time)->format('d-m-Y H-i-s-e') }}` dont include `@` inside

Comment: share value of `$item->time` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show date in html table using Laravel MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912710/show-date-in-html-table-using-laravel-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H-i-s-e', $item->time)->toDateTimeString(); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same question I asked 2 months earlier and already I find the best solution here is a link: [Show date in HTML using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912710/show-date-in-html-table-using-laravel-mongodb/50186848#50186848)

Comment: you can mark as duplicate this question, instead providing link in answer

Comment: click on `flag` below the question and `a duplicate ...` and provide link there